# Extraction of modes from a multi-modal density function

Tags: machine-learning, nonparametric, density-estimation, highest-density-region

I am trying to extract modes from a multi-modal density function and not just peaks. For example, in the two density functions below (images), I would like to extract the curves contained in the black circles and ellipses. We consider that we don't know the a priori number of modes and we can't visualize the curve of the density function since I deal with hundreds of them.

I have not found concrete solutions on the internet. I will be grateful for any help.

[image: probability density function]

[image: probability density function]

Comment: If your plots are representative, then you might want to model your data as [tag:gaussian-mixture-distribution]s with an unknown number of components. You might want to search for ways to do so, perhaps look through our threads with that tag.